# Why don't all cache clearing methods provided by swr work?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, swr

If you check the cache part of swr's official manual, there is a Modify the Cache Data tab. This tab contains information on deleting all caches of swr and have example code

When a member logs out of the service, all cache data needs to be deleted, so we used the example below.

[image]

An error occurred if you used the example as is, so use it as follows.

[image]

The conclusion is that the cache is not deleted. If you log out and create a new user and then connect, the previous user's data will be present. If you refresh through mutate, the data of the user who signed up normally will be displayed.

What I want is not a method of inserting the key value and mutating for all requests, but I want a simple method of deleting it at once when logging out. The manual provided by swr also explains the method, but it does not work.

Why isn't it working? I am using it in ReactNative, the swr version is swr@2.2.1.

```
mutate('*', undefind, false)
```

I tried this method too, but it didn't work. help!

Comment: Which VS code extension do you use to show arguments names

Comment: I'm not using vscode, I'm using intellij, what extension do I need to use this feature?